# Sum of last_value of each partition in SQL with window functions

Tags: sql, sum, time-series, aggregate-functions, amazon-timestream

I have a table that stores total disk used at any point in time for each entity. I want to find the peak disk used in a time period.
For example, the data looks something like

*Note: The timestamp is actual timestamp with seconds precision, I set it to 10am etc for brevity*

```
timestamp | entity_id | disk_used
---------------------------------
    9am   |         1 |  10
   10am   |         2 |  20
   11am   |         2 |  15
   12am   |         1 |  12
```

In this example, the max disk used at is 30 (10 from entity 1 and 20 from entity 2).

I have tried a number of approaches.

1. Sum of (max of each entity) does't work because it would give the result 20 + 12 = 32. But before the entity 1 increased its size, the entity 2 reduced the size, so the peak disk usage was 30.
2. I tried to use window function to find the sum of last_value of each entity

```
select timestamp, entity_id,
    disk_used, 
    sum(last_value(disk_used) over(
        partition by entity_id order by timestamp)
    ) sum_of_last
```

attempting to generate, so I can then max of it,

```
timestamp | entity_id | disk_used | sum_of_last
-----------------------------------------------
    9am   |         1 |  10       |   10
   10am   |         2 |  20       |   30
   11am   |         2 |  15       |   25       // (10 + 15)
   12am   |         1 |  12       |   27       // (12 + 15)
```

however, that query doesn't work because we cannot aggregate over a window function in ISO Standard SQL 2003. I am using Amazon timestream db. The query engine is compatible with ISO Standard SQL 2003.

--
Rephrasing the same question, at each timestamp we have the data point, for the total disk used at that instant.
To find the total total disk used at that instant, sum the last value of each entity.

Is there an effective way to compute this?

Comment: (1) SQL 2003?  Please tag with the database you are using.  (2) What results do you want?

Comment: We ae using amazon timestream, it is a new timeseries database from amazon. The query I heard is compatible with SQL 2003. (And has some additional functions)

Comment: . . Perhaps the reference is to ISO Standard SQL 2003.  Just "sql 2003" seems awkward without the reference.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find the peak disk used in a time period

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select max(sum_disk_used)
from (
    select time, sum(disk_used) as sum_disk_used
    from mytable
    group by time
) t
```

The subquery computest the total `disk_used` at each point in time, then the outer query gets the peak value only.

If your database supports some kind of `limit` clause, this can be simplified:

```
select time, sum(disk_used) as sum_disk_used
from mytable
group by time
order by sum_disk_used limit 1
```

To filter on a given period, you would typically add a `where` clause to the subquery.

Comment: This doesn't work, I the timestamp in the table is a timestamp, I put that as 10am, 11am etc for brevity.

Comment: I want to find the peak disk usage for the whole day.

Comment: @JackDaniels: the datatype of the `time` column does not make a difference for the query I provided. Please explain what is wrong with the results that you are getting.

Comment: I think I will change the example, assume the time for the first row is 9am. In that case, your example, will give the result as 20, not 30 that we would want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two entities, you can do:

```
select t.*,
       (last_value(case when entity_id = 1 then disk_used end ignore nulls) over (order by time) +
        last_value(case when entity_id = 2 then disk_used end ignore nulls) over (order by time)
       ) as total        
from t;
```

One way to generalize this for all entities is to generate a row for each entity at each time, impute the value and aggregate:

```
select ti.time, e.entity_id,
       last_value(disk_used ignore nulls) over (partition by e.entity_id order by t.time) as imputed_disk_used
from (select distinct time from t) ti cross join
     (select distinct entity_id from t) e left join
     t
     on ti.time = t.time and e.entity_id = t.entity_id;
```

Then you can aggregate:

```
select time, sum(imputed_disk_used)
from (select ti.time, e.entity_id,
             last_value(disk_used ignore nulls) over (partition by e.entity_id order by t.time) as imputed_disk_used
      from (select distinct time from t) ti cross join
           (select distinct entity_id from t) e left join
           t
           on ti.time = t.time and e.entity_id = t.entity_id
     ) te
group by time;
```

However, this gives that value *per time* rather than per time and `entity_id`.

Comment: this doesn't work because in the example I gave, it would almost be equal to the same as the disk used.

Comment: sorry, the number of entities can be hundreds of thousands. I gave the simplified example to reproduce an issue as generally recommended by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (
    select PrimaryKeyColumn,time
        , sum(disk_used) Over (Partition by EntityId Order by time ) as 
        sum_disk_used
        ,Last_Value(PrimaryKeyColumn) Over (Partition by EntityId Order by 
    time) as Id
    from mytable
) t
where Id=PrimaryKeyColumn
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).
First edit your code to look like code instead of text.